# F# Quadruple Double Function

Tags: f#

According to the TryF#.org site this function below returns quadruple of the number entered.

```
let quadruple x =    
    let double x = x * 2

double(double(x))
```

Can anyone explain why as I interpret it as like follows? Quadruple doesn't perform any mutation or multiple calls.

```
function quadruple(x)
  return function double(x)
    return x * 2
```

or C#

```
int a(int x) { return b(x); }
int b(int x) { return x * 2; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is just a confused indentation. The function should probably look like this:

```
let quadruple x =    
    let double x = x * 2
    double(double(x))
```

This should hopefully make more sense - the `quadruple` function defines a function `double` and then calls it on the input `x` (multiplying it by 2) and then applies `double` on the result, multiplying it by 2 again, so the result is `(x * 2) * 2`.

Using the indentation in your sample, the code would not compile, because it is not syntactically valid (a function body cannot end with a `let` line - it needs to end with an expression representing some result to be returned).

Comment: Actually, that's the exact code that the site outputs to it's evaluation window. Spacing is just copy/paste.